# Python dataclass: Check that a field is in list of possible values

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-class

I want a field in a Python dataclass to only have certain possible values.
For instance, I want a `Jewel` dataclass, whose field `material` can only accept values "gold", "silver", and "platinum".
I came up with this solution:

```py
@dataclass
class Jewel:
    kind: str
    material: str
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        ok_materials = ["gold", "silver", "platinum"]
        if self.material not in ok_materials:
            raise ValueError(f"Only available materials: {ok_materials}.")
```

So, `Jewel("earrings", "silver")` would be ok, whereas `Jewel("earrings", "plastic")` would raise a `ValueError`.

Is there a better or more pythonic way to achieve this? Maybe something that relies on features from dataclasses module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also propose the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library, which enables type validation when loading JSON or dict data to a dataclass type, such as with the `fromdict` helper function for example.

To make it simple, you could still pass in a string but use `typing.Literal` to enforce strict value checks. Alternatively, you *could* define an `Enum` class to hold the possible values, in case that works a little better for you.

Here is an example using [`typing.Literal`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/) to restrict the possible values. In Python 3.7 or earlier, I would import `Literal` from the `typing_extensions` module instead.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Literal

from dataclass_wizard import fromdict
from dataclass_wizard.errors import ParseError


@dataclass
class Jewel:
    kind: str
    # ok_materials = ["gold", "silver", "platinum"]
    material: Literal['gold', 'silver', 'platinum']


print(fromdict(Jewel, {'kind': 'test', 'material': 'gold'}))
print()

# following should raise a `ParseError`, as 'copper' is not in
# the valid Literal values.
try:
    _ = fromdict(Jewel, {'kind': 'test', 'material': 'copper'})
except ParseError as e:
    print(e)
```

The output is nice and clean, with a **clear** error message displayed about what went wrong:

```
Jewel(kind='test', material='gold')

Failure parsing field `material` in class `Jewel`. Expected a type Literal, got str.
  value: 'copper'
  error: Value not in expected Literal values
  allowed_values: ['gold', 'silver', 'platinum']
  json_object: '{"kind": "test", "material": "copper"}'
```

*Disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintenor of this library.

Comment: Thanks, dataclass-wizard seems an interesting library!
The solution requires a third-party library but is certainly Pythonic, and it takes advantage of modern Python functionality, like type hints.

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is exactly what [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)s are made for.

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class Material(Enum):
...     gold = 1
...     silver = 2
...     platinum = 3
...
>>> Material.diamond
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\enum.py", line 341, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: diamond
>>> Material.gold
<Material.gold: 1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late to the party, but if you only want to validate for that simple scenario you can try chili library: https://github.com/kodemore/chili

Chili has a type integrity validation built-in which will work for your scenario, consider the following example:

```py
from enum import Enum
from chili import init_dataclass

class Material(Enum):
    SILVER = "silver"
    GOLD = "gold"
    PLATINUM = "platinum"


@dataclass
class Jewel:
    kind: str
    material: Material

j1 = init_dataclass({"kind": "test", "material": "silver"}, Jewel)  # this works fine

j2 = init_dataclass({"kind": "test", "material": "test"}, Jewel)  # this will fail with a ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks, also chili seems like an interesting library!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create ok_materials as a set instead.
2. According to PEP-8, you should put the not before self.material
3. ok_materials should rather be a class attribute (at least from what I see of your class)
4. If you don't want the user to modify ok_materials, you can put an underscore at the beggining.
   In terms of dataclass specificities, I am clearly not familiar enough with this class to give an answer.